# HIVE UDF error while creating

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, udf

While creating an UDF for HIVE, I am getting below error:

```
org.apache.ambari.view.hive.client.HiveErrorStatusException: 
H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask [ERROR_STATUS]
```

I am working on hortonworks platform. I tried to create a simple UDF to simulate the issue, is this a config issue?

### UDF

```
package HiveUDF.HIVEUDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
public final class HIVEUDFUPPER extends UDF
{
 public Text evaluate(final Text s) {
    if (s == null) { return null; }
    return new Text(s.toString().toUpperCase());
}
}
```

---

```
add jar hdfs:///tmp/HIVEUDF.jar;
create temporary function HIVEUDFUPPER as 'HIVEUDFUPPER';
```

Comment: for add jar you require to provide file system jar file path and not hdfs one. Suggestion is to copy the generated jar file to <hive-installation-dir>/lib/ directory, and do add jar by providing path to <hive-installation-dir>/lib/<YOUR_UDF.jar>

Comment: Also you need to provide the complete class path , so 'HiveUDF.HIVEUDF.HIDEUDFUPPER'.

Comment: By the way, the naming of your class/package is against java conventions and will make most Java programmers cringe.  Class name should not be all uppercase , and neither should packages.  Packages are actually always lowercase and begin with your org's domain. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html